# How do I add watermark text to a bitmap in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

I would like to do something like this http://weblogs.asp.net/broux/archive/2011/02/08/silverlight-how-to-watermark-a-writeablebitmapimage-with-a-text.aspx.  I am having a tough time getting this to work in WinRT.  I am using the WriteableBitmap extensions to "render" some text but I want it to look exactly like it looks in this example.  Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render that text to a png asset and blit it on top of the bitmap. Unless the text needs to be dynamic - then you'd need DirectWrite. WinRT XAML Toolkit has an extension method you could use to render text to a WriteableBitmap.

Comment: Filip is right. You can use a static PNG you prepare before and then use the WriteableBitmapEx Blit method.

Comment: Unfortunately all of it is dynamic.

Comment: Well then DirectWrite is what you need.

Comment: Can you show me an example what you mean?  Can I do this through SharpDx?

Comment: Yes, you can use DirectWrite with SharpDx. There is an example for doing this here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/513187/Paste-Date-Time-Stamp-While-Capturing-Image-in-Win

Comment: I will try this later.  If this works then I will add it to your answer and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the job done visually:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" />
    <Image Source="{Binding MyWatermark}" />
</Grid>
```

It's certainly the same effect without all the work. If you are wanting to get it to literally make the watermark part of the original image, offloading to a service is your only current option. Without the `Render()` method on the `WriteableBitmap` there is no other option for you. Not even the XAML Toolkit solves this problem. It's a common request.

But depending on your use case, this might just be exactly what you want!

I hope it is. Best of luck.

Comment: I want to do all of it dynamically and then get a copy of the image in memory.