# add watermark on image in windows8

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I can find lots of threads and blogs which related to add watermark to image, but all of them are using GDI+, in winrt, it couldn't work. Anyone know how to add watermark to image in windows 8 app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add watermark text to a bitmap in WinRT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352717/how-do-i-add-watermark-text-to-a-bitmap-in-winrt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets the job done visually:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" />
    <Image Source="{Binding MyWatermark}" />
</Grid>
```

Same answer as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509282/265706

Comment: Read the answer, it is not possible. Scratch that, it is possible, but it requires that you write it in C++. It really is not possible in C# / WinRT at this time.

Comment: is this still true? I notice that there are apps in the windows phone store that do stuff like chromakey (green screen) which I'm assuming is a similar concept. are those silverlight only apps or is there now a way to overlay one image on top of another in phone 8.1 rt?

Comment: Yes, you can render a full XAML tree to a Bitmap now. :)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the Lumia Imaging SDK will let you do this. We tested it with an HTC device and it worked so it does appear to support windows phones from other manufacturers...

here's a blog post I wrote about using the SDK to crop and blend (watermark) photos, and it includes a sample project to see the code in action.

http://blog.falafel.com/crop-blend-watermark-photos-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-the-lumia-imaging-sdk/

I hope this is helpful!

EDIT: I just realized your question was for Windows we did not try this with windows, only phone, but the documentation states it works with Windows 8.1 devices, I'll have to test this and see what happens!